# Using Salesforce oauth to make calls to own account/app

Tags: oauth, rest

We use salesforce in our website. I'm new to it, and still can't find a way to calls REST api to our own account without going long way of visiting oauth login page, granting access etc(oauth flow).

For example with twitter I just need consumer_key and consumer_secret to update status in my own account.

Is there same way to work with salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to use one of the oAuth flows: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

One of which is the username / password flow where you could use an integration user.

Or develop your own custom RESTRESOURCE

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm

Which you can design to not required any authentication. However, this way requires you do design the rest api yourself.

Comment: used username/password flow, did not find another solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JWT Bearer Flow, which will give you the power to interact with SFDC in a headless *(without browser)* environment.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5